# iOS-chart : Can we how bar chart for ZERO value

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I would like to show some customized way for ZERO value on bar chart because the user can't see that the value is ZERO. I am attaching the screenshot here.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to represent ZERO on the chart. I added some icon to the bar with ZERO value.

```
BarChartDataEntry(x: x_, y: y_, icon: UIImage(named: "icon"))
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Well...Basically no.
As far as i know .. id think so that the value can be ZERO..

`Search Google for more info..`

Comment: Thanks, I ended my problem by showing icon for ZERO value bar chart :)